# How do I pass 2 arguments to an array_map function in php?

Tags: php, mysql, web-deployment-project

```
$sql="select * from question_test where test_id='".$test_id."'   and  difficulty_level   BETWEEN  ".$_SESSION['difficulty_start']." and  ".$_SESSION['difficulty_end']." and question_id NOT IN ('".implode("', '", array_map('mysqli_real_escape_string', $_SESSION['question_attempt']))."')  order by rand()*favourability_level  desc";
```

On running the above code I get an error :

> Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given in C:\xampp\htdocs\exam.php on line 359

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a callback function instead

```
function array_map_callback($a)
{
  global $con;
  return mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $a);
}

array_map('array_map_callback', $_SESSION['question_attempt']);
```

where `$con` is the connection variable.

So your `$sql` variable would be:

```
$sql="select * from question_test where test_id='".$test_id."' and  difficulty_level BETWEEN  ".$_SESSION['difficulty_start']." and  ".$_SESSION['difficulty_end']." and question_id NOT IN ('".implode("', '", array_map('array_map_callback', $_SESSION['question_attempt']))."')  order by rand()*favourability_level  desc";
```

or you can go with [array_walk](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php)

```
array_walk($_SESSION['question_attempt'], function(&$string) use ($con) { 
  $string = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $string);
});
```

Comment: Or `array_map(function($a) use($con) { ...}, $_SESSION['question_attempt'])`.

Comment: @Sougata wow.. I was adding that to my answer and you commented!

Comment: Thanks a lot  , you saved my sanity , I had brooded over this for entire last  day .